# Simplest way to check if string contain specified patterns

Tags: regex, perl

Given a string S, What is the simplest way to check whether a string contains following patters:

```
AnyString:AnyString.SUB
```

Where Sub= Exe or Wav or Mp3 or Bmp.

Example:

```
foo:bar.Exe
a:b.Bmp
cde:uiweiuew.Mp3   
wuyuewy27626:28732.Wav
```

are valid strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following regex:

```
^[^:]+:[^.]+\.(?:Exe|Wav|Mp3|Bmp)$
```